# controlling ethernet speeds in lan c++ windows

Tags: c++, performance, limit, ethernet

I am wondering if it is possible to limit/control ethernet upload and download speeds on specific transport layers (tcp/udp) using c++? I am trying to make a simple to use program that can control the speeds of any device that the ethernet is connected to. For example: Computer B is connected to computer A via Internet Connection Sharing, I use my program to limit computer B's download or upload speed to 120kbs (or any number i choose), with this I would also like to choose udp or tcp.

Basically, I want to create my own program similar to net limiter and other such software, but I also want to add my own features which many of which lack for my needs. These other features are easy enough, but I have no idea how to go about the actual limting process.

Answer (score 0):

The way forward in the general case you ask about would be to create a virtual network adapter and all the monitored route traffic through it. Once that was done, then you can monitor streams between hosts or on specific ports.

Not an easy job... A starting point would be the Windows device driver kit.

If you were prepared to limit just one app, and could modify it, the task would be much simpler... wget and curl for example both offer limiting.

HTH, Ruth